# Side-by-side Panel Directive

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I have an Angular JS directive that iterates through some grouped data and creates panels based on the grouping. I am having difficulty separating these panels into lined groups of two. I have tried editing the placement and value of `col-lg-6` and even played around adding bits of regular CSS that is supposed to accomplish the task. Can someone please take a look at the base code at http://plnkr.co/edit/cNFNAU?p=info and provide any helpful feedback?

Comment: Looks like you're using a Bootstrap row without using a Bootstrap container. 

Try wrapping your order-mapping-container class in a <div class="container"></div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `style.css`, there is a rule...

```
margin: 10px;
```

Because `col-lg-6` basically sets the element's width to 50%... when the margin is added, 2 `col-lg-6`'s are wider than 100% and cannot fit on a row. Remove the margin and it should work.

To add the margins back, you'll need to play around with styles or the layout, keeping in mind not to add positive horizontal margins to the `col-lg-6` elements.

Here it is with the fix (changed lg to xs so it shows properly in plunker)...
[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/5XSXaHj9s5XRqMLWGjwr?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you can do this 2 ways.

The easy way is to use float left style on your divs, but you'll end up with blank spaces when panel heights don't match. See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wdjaa2/%22plunker%22)

The other is to create to div's in your directive and stack even panels one side and odd panels the other. See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1GqFlP)